# Handling Cookies in Ocamlnet

Tags: cookies, http-headers, ocaml

I'm trying to write a bot pulling some data which is only available to authenticated users. I settled for `ocaml (v. 3.12.1)` and `ocamlnet (v. 3.6.5)`. The first part of the script sends a POST request to the website and by the html I receive back, I can tell that the authentication worked (`p1` and `p2`'s values in this code sample are obviously not the ones I'm using).

```
open Http_client
open Nethttp

let pipeline = new pipeline

let () =
  let post_call = new post
    "http://www.kraland.org/main.php?p=1&a=100"
    [("p1", "username");
     ("p2", "password");
     ("Submit", "Ok!")]
  in
  pipeline#add post_call;
  pipeline#run();
```

Then I extract the cookies where the php session id, the account name, a hash of the password, etc. are stored, put them in the header of the next request and run it. And this is where I run into troubles: I systematically get the boring page every anonymous visitor gets.

```
let cookies = Header.get_set_cookie post_call#response_header in
let get_call = new get "http://www.kraland.org/main.php?p=1" in
let header = get_call#request_header `Base in
Header.set_set_cookie header cookies;
pipeline#add get_call;
pipeline#run();
```

When I print the content of the cookies, I do get something weird: I would expect the domain of the cookies to be `kraland.org` but it does not seem to be the case. This is the printing command I use together with the output:

```
List.iter (fun c -> Printf.printf "%.0f [%s%s:%b] %s := %s\n"
  (match c.cookie_expires with None -> -1. | Some f -> f)
  (match c.cookie_domain with None -> "" | Some s -> s)
  (match c.cookie_path with None -> "" | Some s -> s)
  c.cookie_secure c.cookie_name c.cookie_value)
  cookies;

-1 [/:false] PHPSESSID := 410b97b0536b3e949df17edd44965926
1372719625 [:false] login := username
1372719625 [:false] id := myid
1372719625 [:false] password := fbCK/0M+blFRLx3oDp+24bHlwpDUy7x885sF+Q865ms=
1372719625 [:false] pc_id := 872176495311
```

Edit: I had a go at the problem using Haskell's Http-conduit-browser and it works like a charm using [something very much like the doc's example](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit-browser/1.7.1.2/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit-Browser.html).